# Phrase search in a text file

Tags: perl, search, text, phrases

Given a phrase like "I am searching for a text" and one text file that contains the list of words.

I have to find the whether each and every combination of the word present in the text file.

For example, I have to search for the occurrence "I", "I am", "I am searching", "I am searching for", "searching for" etc.

I prefer to write this in perl and I needed a optimal solution that runs faster.

Example text file :

```
I \n
am searching \n
Text \n
searching for \n 
searching for a \n
for searching       ---> my program should not match this 
etc
```

Comment: What's the question?? And what have you tried?

Comment: Can you show an example of the file as well?

Comment: this isn't really a "program this for me please" site. Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I dont need a program I need a idea or algorithm to do

Comment: example text file
I 
I am searching
text

Comment: I have tried to save all the phrase in a hash and do the search against another hash that contains the text . But how do I match possiblities of phrases ?

Comment: So you're trying to search for any permutation of the phrase "I am searching for a text"?  Does it have to include all of the words? Can words be included more than once?  Does it have to be a grammatically correct English sentence?  Knowing the answer to these questions will help people better understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: exactly,I want the permutation. It can even have a single word of the phrase. Words should be in same sequence .ie. "for searching" is not valid. No need for grammar check.

Comment: @Sishanth, But with "for searching", "for" *and* "searching" are both one-word matches

Comment: No if "for" is present ,my possibility of words are only "for","for a","for a text"

Comment: @Sishanth, so in other words, you want the *whole* line to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below prints all the sub_phrases that you want to match.

```
$phrase = 'I am searching for a text';
$\ = "\n";

@words = ();
print "Indices:";
while( $phrase =~ /\b\w+\b/g ) {
    push @words, {word => $&, begin => $-[0], end => $+[0]};
}

$num_words = $#words + 1;
print 'there are ', $num_words, ' words';


for( $i=0; $i<$num_words; $i++ ) {
    for( $j=$i; $j<$num_words; $j++ ) {
        ($start,$finish) = ($words[$i]->{begin}, $words[$j]->{end});
        $sub_phrase = substr $phrase, $start, $finish-$start;
        print "$i-$j: $sub_phrase";
    }
}
```

some explanations:

1. $\ just to make 'print' easier
2. $phrase - using your sample
3. @words is an array of references to records
4. each record is a hash with the word itself, index to the beginning and index to the end of the word
5. I've a regular expression, and I'm iterating. I'm looking for a word boundary, 1 or more word character, and a word boundary.
6. $+ and $- are special variables for the indices of the match of the last RE
7. $& is a special variable for the match of the last RE
8. I then have a nested loop: $i, the outer loop variable is the first word. $j is the last word. That covers all the combinations.
9. I'm calculating $sub_phrase from the beginning of the first word, to the end of the last word.

To complete your exercise, you want to save all the sub_phrase's into an array (instead of 'print' do 'push' into an @permutations). then iterate through your text file, and for each line, try to match against each permutation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really this will help me . Taking permutation for 6 words is reasonable. But If I take permutation for say 40 words , Do you think my search will take much time ?  If so What can be the alternative way ?

Comment: @Sishanth: 1st, technically, these aren't "permutation", but "segments" or "sub-string", because you keep the order of the original phrase. It is really a tradeoff between the size of the text file and the size of the original phrase. The number of segments is O(n^2) where n is the number of words, so you have about 800 segments. You can '|'.join() the phrases into a big RE which I think will perform reasonable. Do that if your text file is enormous. Alternatively, for each line in your text file, you can look it up within the phrase. Do that if text file is relatively short to #words.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an expression that works for all those cases. Below, I show how to *construct* one in Perl (although you can just use the product for your purposes).

```
use List::Util qw<reduce>;

our ( $a, $b );

my $regex       
    = "\n^\n( "
    . join( "\n| "
    , @{( reduce { 
            my $r = ref( $a ) ? $a : [ "$a " ];
            my $s = $r->[0];
            [ "$b (?> [ ] $s)?", @$r ] 
        } 
        reverse split ' ', 'I am searching for a text'
        )}
    )
    . "\n)\n\\s*\n\$"
    ;
say join( "\n# ", split "\n", $regex );

# ^
# ( I (?> [ ] am (?> [ ] searching (?> [ ] for (?> [ ] a (?> [ ] text )?)?)?)?)?
# | am (?> [ ] searching (?> [ ] for (?> [ ] a (?> [ ] text )?)?)?)?
# | searching (?> [ ] for (?> [ ] a (?> [ ] text )?)?)?
# | for (?> [ ] a (?> [ ] text )?)?
# | a (?> [ ] text )?
# | text 
# )
# \s*
# $

map { say foreach m/$regex/xo } <DATA>;
```

- I have added the anchors, since you indicated that it should match the whole line.
- There are spaces in the finished regex, but it uses `/x` to ignore them. That is why we specify the space with `[ ]`.
- The grouping notation `(?>...)` is a variation on the non-capturing `(?:...)`, but fails a lot faster. See [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3epattern)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3epattern%29)
- See [**`List::Util::reduce`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil#reduce)

Comment: Also nice (and tricky) answer. +1. I wonder if performance will be better than the RE that can be generated with my answer, which is much longer but more explicit RE.

Comment: @Uri, it appears that *your* alternation would be faster. However, if you make each choice an independent subexpression, the faster fail improves on that by +67%!